# How can I automate changing the quality of several photos?

Tags: photos, automator, applescript

I would like to be able to reduce the quality of the photos I have in a directory through some sort of automation.  One of the requirements is that I cannot change the dimensions of the photo.  The way I have been doing it so far is just by

- opening each photo in preview
- choosing save as
- selecting jpeg
- selecting a low quality
- saving

This can take a long time when I have over 100 photos.  Is there an easy way to automate this with AppleScript, or through any other sort of means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple Applescript that uses the Image Events built into OS X. Add salt to taste.

```
property kFileList : {}

tell application "Finder"
    set theSourceFolder to choose folder
    set theDestinationFolder to choose folder

    my createList(theSourceFolder)

    set lastItem to (count kFileList)
    repeat with thisItem from 1 to lastItem
        set theFile to (theSourceFolder & item thisItem of kFileList) as string

        tell application "Image Events"
            set theImage to open theFile
            save theImage as JPEG2 in ((theDestinationFolder & item thisItem of kFileList & ".jpg") as string) with compression level high
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell

on createList(mSource_folder)
    set item_list to ""

    tell application "System Events"
        set item_list to get the name of every disk item of mSource_folder
    end tell

    set item_count to (get count of items in item_list)

    repeat with i from 1 to item_count
        set the_properties to ""

        set the_item to item i of the item_list
        set the_item to ((mSource_folder & the_item) as string) as alias

        tell application "System Events"
            set file_info to get info for the_item
        end tell

        if visible of file_info is true then
            set file_name to displayed name of file_info
            set end of kFileList to file_name
            if folder of file_info is true then
                my createList(the_item)
            end if
        end if

    end repeat
end createList
```

[Acorn](http://flyingmeat.com/acorn/) is also good for cheap and easy automation via Applescript that will offer more choices than what Image Events, but Image Events is free so there's that